# How to create a new source and set as default source on Stripe API

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

I'm looking for a way to create a new source for a customer and then set that source as the default source for the customer. The problem I'm currently facing is that the response from creating the source does not give me a easy way to identify the id for the new created source so that I can set that source as default.

Below is my code, without any API key and customer ID:

```
           \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe_api_key);

            $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($_SESSION['parent']['stripe_customer_id']);

            $customer->sources->create(array('source' => array("object" => "card", 'exp_month' => $expire_month, 'exp_year' => $expire_year, 'number' => $card_number, 'address_line1' => $billing_address1, 'address_line2' => $billing_address2, 'address_city' => $billing_city, 'address_zip' => $billing_postal_code, 'address_country' => $billing_country, 'currency' => 'GBP', 'cvc' => $security_code, 'name' => $_SESSION['parent']['firstname'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['parent']['lastname'])))->__toArray(true);

            //set as default
            if (isset($_POST['check_default_source'])) {
                $customer->default_source=$customer['id'];
                $customer->save();    
            }
```

Comment: In the second last statement the customer ID should be replaced with the source ID and like I said Stripe sends back all the sources and I don't know how to get the ID of the source that have just been created.

Comment: I was thinking I can add something in the metadata attribute than reference that in the response. Is the there an easier way?

Comment: Struggling with the same thing right now, and using an old API/PHP library... don't feel like updating all my stuff just to fix this one problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem, slightly different.

I added a new source from a token_id.

The `getLastResponse` method was not available in my API or library version.

But using the token object (Stripe::Token::retreive( token_id )) you can actually retrieve the card_id, and use that to update the default_source.

Took me a long time to figure this out, so I post it here. Maybe it helps someone in the future...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to to find the solution to my question. Stripe API does send back the id of the source that was just created and to get the ID I use the below code:

```
$source_id = json_decode($customer->sources->getLastResponse()->body)->id;
```